# Unable to deploy the osgi bundle using auto-deploy profile(cqblueprints)

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, aem

We are using cqblueprints archetype for building our cq project (eclipse/cqblueprints). But while trying to deploy the acme-corporate-services (the project which contains the bundle), using

```
    mvn -Pauto-deploy install
```

command, we are getting the following error.

```
    [INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:install (default-install) @ acme-corporate-services ---
[INFO] Installing com/acme/wcm/cq/acme-corporate-services/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/acme-corporate-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Writing OBR metadata
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-sling-plugin:2.1.0:install (install-bundle) @ acme-corporate-services ---
[INFO] Installing Bundle com.acme.wcm.cq.acme-corporate-services(C:\acme_CORP_REFACTOR\acme-corporate\acme-corporate-services\target\acme-corporate-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) to http://localhost:4502/apps/acme-corporate/install via PUT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.831 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-20T07:35:35-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/42M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.sling:maven-sling-plugin:2.1.0:install (install-bundle) on project acme-corporate-services: Installation on http://localhost:4502/apps/acme-corporate/install failed, cause: Installation failed, cause: Conflict -> [Help 1]
```

Please help us to find the root cause for this error.

Comment: Does this path /apps/acme-corporate/install exist in your repo ?

Comment: @rakhi4110 How can I verify that ..

Comment: Check in your CRXDELite whether the folder install is present under /apps/acme-corporate

Comment: Thanks it got worked, have crated a folder following the structure /apps/acme-corporate/install . But, currently I have a folder called acme under apps to store my components. Is there any naming conventions that I should follow while creating the application structure in CRXDE lite?

Comment: You can refer [this link](http://www.praveenmodi.com/adobe-aem-cq5-development-for-beginners-how-to-setup-a-new-cq-application-project/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above mentioned error might occur if the installation directory is **missing** in the repository.

In your case maven is trying to on `/apps/acme-corporate/install`. If the above path doesn't exist then you might get the *Conflict* error.

Check whether the required directory exists in the repo, and in case it doesn't, try creating one.

Comment: Some reference discussion http://apache-sling.73963.n3.nabble.com/Issue-using-PUT-with-maven-sling-plugin-and-non-existent-path-td3885587.html